# Reading all process output before process closes

Tags: java, process, multiprocessing, race-condition

I'm reading separate process console output using standard code:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder(exeArgs);
b.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = b.start();
try (BufferedReader inputReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    String output;
    while ((output = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
       // do something with output
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the process ends faster than I read output, a portion of the output is lost.

The easiest way to reproduce the problem is to put a breakpoint on the `try` expression and wait for a second before continuing program execution. Doing this will prevent you from getting any output at all. E.g. inputReader.readLine() will never return a string.

Is there are a way to cache process output to ensure it's always read completely?

Comment: You misunderstood the problem. Try to run "ls" process and stop on breakpoint. It works fine and prints directory content.

Answer (score 0):

It seems on Windows the console buffer size is limited and you should read it as quickly as possible to avoid buffer overflow and losing a portion of data. The only reliable solution I found after reading several answers here and reading blog posts on topic is to read the console output in a separate thread as quickly as possible.

Here is a simple code implementing the task in Kotlin:

```
typealias GobblerCallback = ((e: String) -> Unit)

class StreamGobbler(private val stream: InputStream, private val lineReadCallback: GobblerCallback? = null) : Thread() {

    override fun run() {
        try {
            val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            while (true) {
                val line = safeReadLine(reader) ?: break
                lineReadCallback?.invoke(line)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle exception if necessary
        }
    }

}

// Sample code that reads full process output
val gobbler1 = StreamGobbler(process.inputStream, callback)
gobbler1.start()
val gobbler2 = StreamGobbler(process.errorStream, callback)
gobbler2.start()
```